# Get more information from a object in serializer and not just the id

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a Serializers and View which work perfectly well, the only problem now is that I want to be able to get the entire data it contains and just the id number. Let me show you:

This is my view:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def TicketListView(request, *args, **kwargs):
    queryset = Order.objects.filter(ordered=True)
    username = request.GET.get('username')
    if username != None:
        queryset = queryset.by_username(username)
    # serializer = PostSerializer(queryset, many=True)
    serializer = TicketListSerializer(
        queryset, many=True, context={'request': request})
    return Response(serializer.data, status=200)
```

Serializers:

```
class TicketListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = '__all__'
```

This is the output:

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "ref_code": "42764745463765476",
        "start_date": "2021-02-24T01:23:27.135638Z",
        "ordered_date": "2021-02-24T01:23:13Z",
        "ordered": true,
        "being_delivered": false,
        "received": false,
        "refund_requested": false,
        "refund_granted": false,
        "transaction_id": "w4234",
        "qr_code": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/qrcode/qr_code-42764745463765476_zaqc1a7.png",
        "user": 1,
        "shipping_address": null,
        "billing_address": null,
        "payment": 1,
        "coupon": null,
        "items": [
            2,
            1
        ]
    }
]
```

Now, instead of the `items` to show `[2,1]`, i want it to show the actual data it contains something like this for `1`.

```
"item": {
                "id": 1,
                "category": "Music",
                "label": "PopSocial",
                "likess": 0,
                "title": "fe",
                "caption": "asfwa",
                "photo": "/media/posts/Premium_SUndays_XhustW8.jpg",
                "date_of_event": "2021-02-24T01:15:10Z",
                "location": "SRID=4326;POINT (5.712891 7.885147)",
                "latitude": "7.885147",
                "longitude": "5.712891",
                "date_posted": "2021-02-24T01:15:11Z",
                "likes": 0,
                "price": "10000.00",
                "discount_price": 343.0,
                "digital": false,
                "slug": "11",
                "author": 1,
                "bookmark": []
            },
            "final_price": 686.0,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Way:
You can use **depth=1** in your serializer.
Here is the docs from official Django Rest Framework
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization.

Second Way:
You can define your ItemSerializer in your TicketListSerializer, then call the items out from ItemSerializer.